# Spam users in Drupal

Tags: drupal, bots, spam

I am using Drupal for the content of my website. I mean, I use it as a content editor, but serve the content with my custom PHP pages. Anyways,

I'm seeing a lot of users that are registering and commenting in my Drupal site, the usernames are like

```
jennipoehmkocmnxqs
traciezlnvafjlasp
frederickajefferson
rowenanskmsqynljyxl
krystle03qgatdzutama
```

So they are obviously coming from one (if not more) bot(s).
And I don't want to implement re-captcha since I want to encourage my visitors to add content. So I need to find a way to find the source of this bot. Maybe an ip address, and block it from my domain. Do you have any idea what bot is this, or how can I track it?

I've looked into Drupal database, apparently it does not save the ip address of users..

Thanks !

### p.s.

And there are also spam comments like this:

```
I'm really enjoying the theme/design of your website. Do you ever run into any web browser compatibility problems? A number of my blog readers have complained about my website not operating correctly in Explorer but looks great in Opera. Do you have any solutions to help fix this issue? Look at my weblog :: _sell my gold_ (link that redirects to www.swiftcashforgold.com/what-we-buy.php)
```

Comment: Blocking an IP won't work.  Botnets are used by many spammers so IP varies.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with fake users on an e-Commerce site that didn't even allow comments.  Implementing reCAPTCHA on the registration and login screens definitely seemed to cut down on the number of fake signups we got quite a bit, but you are definitely correct about it being an annoyance to users and a bit of a barrier to their activity, and in a lot of cases it just doesn't work because humans are filling it out.

A different approach that will at least help you deal with the comments is analyzing the content of the comment and determining if it is spam that way.  For this, you can use [Mollom](http://mollom.com/), [Akismet](http://akismet.com/), [Defensio](http://www.defensio.com/), or a similar solution.  These services are configured by default not to display a CAPTCHA, but they instead check the patterns of the many submissions that run through their respective services, and are in many cases they are able to auto-detect spam and "quarantine" bad comments due to the wealth of information they have.

These are all subscription services with free starter plans.  If you have a lot of legit comments coming into your site on a daily basis, you will have to pay a monthly fee.  All of these solutions have Drupal modules which allow for their integration into Drupal forms.

I know Mollom also supports protecting the user registration form by default, but I don't know for sure if any of these modules will completely solve the problem of fake users signing up because I haven't tried it yet.  It's possible that one or more of these modules will mark a user for leaving spam comments.  Hopefully this will help with both problems, but it will definitely stop the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate that email addresses of people that register, actually exist.

This can be done using the PHP class (below) that sends SMTP commands to their email server, but not an actual email.

That way you know they are valid users (and where they came from) without actually sending them pestering emails.

http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/smtpvalidateclassphp/